# Android sysfs read

Tags: android, sysfs

I'm trying to read and display data from an already-existing sysfs file under 
/sys/bus/ that's been created independent of the android app I'm trying to develop.

I'm having trouble finding documentation on how to read files that haven't been created locally within the android app. How do I read from an already existing kernel file? It seems like InputStream and similar objects and related methods are only for reading local files.

Comment: No, it's effectively a file, so ordinary file functions should work fine.  The only real questions are a: if sysfs is mounted for your application process (there are now some difference between what is mounted and where for apps vs adb) and b: if you have read permission to the node of interest

Comment: Thanks! The sysfs file is mounted, but I'm not sure if I have permission to read it. When I try FileReader f = new FileReader(<path to file>), and then f.read(buffer), I receive an uncaught exception. How do I check if I have permission in general? I tried looking for internal storage permission on the android permissions list but the closest I found was a permission to read external storage.

Comment: You might install a terminal emulator like connectbot and try it manually.  Generally these are not android-style permissions, but how-android-configures-linux ones, and as a result they'd be the same for all 3rd party apps so a test with a different app like connectbot is likely to be representative for what yours could do.  But it's all subject to change on a different device/android version.